# How to do a google sheet cell similar match

Tags: javascript

I want to search each cell in a column for a similar match. How do I do that? e.g. if cell value is "New delhi" the search id " New" should search the cell instead of the full text.I am unable to use Match with if.

```js
function doGet(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  

function search(e){
 var id = e.parameter.id;
  
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  let a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == id || values[i][1] == id) {
      a.push(values[i][2]);
    }
  }
  if(a) return ContentService.createTextOutput(a.join(',')).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  
}
```